# umbraco razor - getting fields from content

Tags: razor, field, umbraco, umbraco-webforms

I have a 6 items of the same content type "news", in each item I have a field newsIntro. I want to put the fields in specific pages on another page so I need to target a specific field so it may be newsIntro on node 1702. I have tried a few things like

@1720.newsIntro

how do I target a specific field

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some great resources you should take a look at while you are learning Razor:

1. [Umbraco Razor Feature Walkthrough](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/2/23/umbraco-47-razor-feature-walkthrough-%E2%80%93-part-1.aspx) - An eight part blog post series of many of the new Razor features in Umbraco 4.7 with examples.
2. [Razor DynamicNode Cheat Sheet](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet) - A PDF of all the properties and methods available to the Razor `DynamicNode` object (that includes `@Model`).
3. [Cultiv Razor Examples](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cultiv-razor-examples) - An Umbraco website that you can download and open with WebMatrix or IIS and see various ways to access properties with Razor.
4. [Razor snippets](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/razor-snippets) - A compilation of different snippets, examples, etc. from Our Umbraco.

But in answer to your question, to get a property of a specific node you have to get the actual `DynamicNode` object first, then use the property alias to access the property value. Example:

```
@{
    //Get the node
    dynamic node = Library.NodeById(1720);

    // Display the property
    @node.newsIntro
}
```

To access a property from the current page, you simply use `Model`:

```
@Model.newsIntro
```

or

```
@Model.bodyText
```

or

```
@Model.Name
```

Answer (score 5):

First, get an IPublishedContent object from the TypedContent method and then use GetPropertyValue to retrieve the value of the field.

```
@{
  int nodeId = 1720;
  IPublishedContent contentNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(nodeId);
  var newsIntro = contentNode.GetPropertyValue("newsIntro");
}

<p>@newsIntro</p>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I needed it from within a `foreach` loop and so it already had the `var item in selection` so I just changed the above to `Umbraco.TypedContent(item.Id)` and left out the first line. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

With Umbraco 7 I used this code to get property from different pages:

```
@Umbraco.Content(1720).newsIntro
```

Comment: To get it from within a `foreach` (using the query builder, for example) substitute the hardcoded id (`1720`) with `item.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

If the content item 1720 is a parent or ancestor of the page where you want to use the value, you can get it recursively like this:

```
@Umbraco.Field("newsIntro", recursive: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get fields from content I have used this:

```
@{
    var selection = Umbraco.TypedContent(contentId).Children()
                        .Where(x => x.IsVisible())
                        .OrderBy("CreateDate");
}
@foreach(var item in selection){
            @item.GetPropertyValue("fieldName1")
            @item.GetPropertyValue("fieldName2")
            @item.GetPropertyValue("fieldName_N")
}
```