# Umbraco, macro, render content into list from doc onto site template part

Tags: razor, macros, umbraco

Complete newby question - I've looked everywhere (as I'm not a .NET dev finding it hard) to create a macro that pulls information from content items create into a list.

Here is the information I would like to present:

```
<style>
ul#showcase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

.showbox {
  border: 2px solid #ffd83d;
  border-color: #ffd83d;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #660000;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  width: 190px;
  height: 152px;
  margin-left: -110px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px -1.5px rgba(62,99,125,.8);
}
.showbox a{
  color: #ffd83d;
  text-align: right;
}
.showbox:hover {
  -moz-transition: margin-left,background-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left,background-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
  -o-transition: margin-left,background-color;
  -o-transition-duration: 3s;
  transition: margin-left,background-color;
  transition-duration:3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color:#ffd83d;
}

.showbox:hover a  {
  position: relative;
  -moz-transition: color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transition: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
  transition: color;
  transition-duration:3s;
  color: #333333;
}

.showbox a:hover  {
  -moz-transition: color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition: color;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition: color;
  transition-duration:1s;
  color: #660000;
}

.showbox-inner {
  position: relative;
  border: 0px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 110px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0px 90px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.showbox-inner:hover {
  -moz-transition: margin-left,background-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left,background-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
  -o-transition-: margin-left,background-color;
  -o-transition--duration: 3s;
  transition: margin-left,background-color;
  transition-duration:3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color:#333333;
}

.showbox-inner p  {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 15px 5px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
    }
  .showbox-image img{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px -10px;
  padding: 0px -10px;
   }

.showbox-inner:hover p {
  -moz-transition:color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-transition: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
  -o-transition-: color;
  -o-transition--duration: 3s;
  transition: color;
  transition-duration:3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color:#ffd83d;
}



</style>

<div>
  <ul id="showcase">
</li>
    <li>
      <div class="showbox"><a href="http://www.moomookwan.org"      target="blank">MooMooKwan</a>
      <div class="showbox-inner">
  <p>Korean MooMooKwan Hapkido Association Australia</p>
      <div class="showbox-image"><img src="../media/11698/MMK.png" width=110px height=110 /></div>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.moomookwan.org" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
            </div></li>
    <li>
      <div class="showbox"><a href="http://www.hapkido.co" target="blank">H.I.A</a>
      <div class="showbox-inner">
  <p>Hapkido International Association Australia</p>
      <div class="showbox-image"><img src="../media/11692/HIA-Logo.png" width=110px height=110 /></img></div>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.hapkido.co" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
            </div></li>
<li>
      <div class="showbox"><a href="http://www.martialartsgoldcoast.net" target="blank">Warrior Hapkido</a>
      <div class="showbox-inner">
      <p>Warrior Hapkido GoldCoast, QLD</p>
      <div class="showbox-image"><img src="../media/11710/warriorhapkido.png" width=110px height=110 /></div>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.martialartsgoldcoast.net" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
            </div></li>
<li>
      <div class="showbox"><a href="http://www.steveshapkido.com.au" target="blank">Steve's Hapkido</a>
      <div class="showbox-inner">
      <p>Steve's Hapkido Brisbane, QLD</p>
      <div class="showbox-image"><img src="../media/11704/SHA-Bris.png" width=110px height=110 /></div>
      </div>
       <a href="http://www.steveshapkido.com.au" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
        </div></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

I've included the style (even though this would be a seperate stylesheet) the issue i have is that every time i create a variable to display the items i want i just seem to make a complete mess of it.

The items i want to display are all "showcaseItem" document types i have created under a "showcaseFolder" off the root node.

The properties i want to display from each showcaseItem are:

dojangName - textstring

dojangUrl - textstring

dojangDescription - simple editor

dojangImage - Image Picker(from media)

Look - obviously i'm lost, ideally this is the "sort" of information i would like to present......

```
<li>
<div class="showbox"><a href="http://@showcaseItem.dojangUrl" target="blank">showcaseItem.dojangName</a>
<div class="showbox-inner">
<p>showcaseItem.dojangDescription</p>
<div class="showbox-image"><img src="showcaseItem.dojangImage" width=110px height=110 />    </div>
</div>
<a href="http://@showcaseItem.dojangUrl" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
</div></li>
```

BUT i just don't know where to go from here so that i can:

1. List each child under the parent folder
2. Limit the list to 5 items that change at random (wish item)

Can anyone help?

Have a look at my dummy site http://propertymj.com (chrome or firefox only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@{
// Get showcaseFolder:
var showcaseFolder = Library.NodeById(folderId);

// For debugging, output the name:
@showcaseFolder.Name

// Get five children at random:
var showcaseItems = showcaseFolder.Children.Random(5);

// For debugging, output the count:
@showcaseItems.Count()

// Iterate through items:
<ul>
@foreach (var item in showcaseItems)
{
    <li>
        <div class="showbox"><a href="http://@item.dojangUrl" target="blank">@item.dojangName</a>
            <div class="showbox-inner">
                <p>@item.dojangDescription</p>
                <div class="showbox-image"><img src="@Library.MediaById(item.dojangImage).umbracoFile" width=110px height=110 /></div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://@item.dojangUrl" target="blank">Click to Visit</a>
        </div>
    </li>
}
</ul>
}
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11119812/1110395) for some good resources on learning more about Umbraco's Razor syntax.

Comment: hi dludlow - i'm getting an error that "0" is not valid at the start of a code block.

is this supposed to be the id of the showcasefolder node - tried that at got the error with a 1 replacing the 0.

any other advice would be great!

Comment: I was going for a more dynamic way of getting to the showcaseFolder. Enter the Id of the showcaseFolder node, instead. I've updated my code. My guess is that there may be some extra characters in your code though. Make sure all of your open tags have corresponding  closes.

Comment: Hi Dludlow - I'm getting the following error.

c:\websites\propjcom\propertymj.com\wwwroot\macroScripts\634810063243250000_showcase.cshtml(45): error CS0103: The name 'showcaseItems' does not exist in the current context

Which is just plain weird.

Comment: @HapkidoCanberra, make sure the whole thing is wrapped in the razor brackets (@{ ...}). I've edited my answer again.

Comment: OMG I cannot believe I forgot that!!

The script passes the umbraco testing - however now nothing is showing.

Comment: OMG I cannot believe I forgot that!!

The script passes the umbraco testing - however now nothing is showing.

You can tell I'm new at this. I'll see if it is the name of the elements I'm getting wrong. 

Or the way I've structured the templates.

Comment: @HapkidoCanberra, you could throw in some extra lines of code to debug the razor. I've edited my answer again. Also check the source of the page and see if anything is being outputted.

Comment: Legend!

I've removed the extra code bit you put it - basically after you had added this it was showing that (even though the children were published) they didn't show.

Once I republished the children - they appeared straight away. 

Thank you sooo much for your help!

Comment: @HapkidoCanberra, I'm glad it worked out! Don't forget to read up on some of those razor resources, I've found them very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Doug, only problem with the information you suggest is that you require an understanding of .NET to get most of it. I'm an HTML/CSS guy.

I appreciate your help.

Tom