# How to display articles / post in homepage in Umbraco 6 (Razor)?

Tags: razor, umbraco

I try move my magazine to Umbraco.

So basically I have in general 3 types of document types:

Home page - which is the home page

Magazine page - which is the achieve by categories (sport / tech / music / etc.)

News page - which is the ongoing news, which have the properties: title, SubTitle, articleImg - which is media picker for the main article image, and articleText - which is it's the article text (rich text editor)

Now what I try to do is to display the title and SubTitle on the home page for each category. As well as in the Magazine pages - which is basically the achieve. So, in the home page I need to display in each div between 4 to 8 posts of each category, and in the magazine pages each category has it's own page (sport / tech / music / etc.)

The question is: How do I do it???

In wordpress theme it's very simple - I just using the php loop for each category. How does though I do it in Umbraco?? (Version 6, with Razor). I'm not using uBlogsy.

Is there any simple way to do it? Any simple script / handler / helper just to show on homepage Image (Thumbnail) then title (under h1) and SubTitle (under h2) for each category? As well as in the achieve pages?

I'm new to Umbraco and didn't find any tutorial how to do it.

Thanks so much!

Meni .

Comment: Can a news page have more than one category?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116644/umbraco-razor-getting-fields-from-content/11119812#11119812) for some good Umbraco razor resources.

Comment: Actually I made just one document type for news page - which everytime that I post news - it will categorize it by the folder it's going to (sports / music / etc) - hope it's the right way to do it... - I just made a document type call "Content Folder" with the alias "umbracoRedirect" so I guess I could sort them by the folder? Or, is there any [other / better ] way to manage categories?