# umbraco item insertTextBefore conditional

Tags: umbraco

I'm working with umbraco and I wonder if it is possible to set the property insertTextBefore conditional. I have the following umbraco item:

```
<umbraco:Item Field="displayTitle" useIfEmpty="pageName" runat="server" />
```

and the page is displaying Events. What I need is to insert "Past" or "Upcoming" depending on the url! Do you know if this is possible or if I need other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where a [macro](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/sitebuilder-introduction/what-are-macros.aspx) comes in handy. You can write simple macros using razor or xslt. I prefer razor as they're easier to wrap my brain around. Here's an example:

```csh
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">

    string type;

    if (condition)
    {
        type = "Upcoming";
    }
    else
    {
        type = "Past";
    }

    @:@type @Model.displayTitle        

</umbraco:Macro>
```

Just replace `condition` with the condition you want to test.

See [umbraco razor - getting fields from content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116644/umbraco-razor-getting-fields-from-content/11119812#11119812) for more information on razor.